# how to send L2CAP Packet to BLE Device

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I have this program [hcidump-crash.c](https://github.com/balle/bluediving/blob/master/tools/hcidump-crash.c)
that sends some l2cap packets to classic bluetooth device. I want to do the same for BLE devices. Please can someone helps me? I don't know how to process

Thank you

Comment: What kind of L2CAP packets? GATT packets?

Comment: No not GATT Packets. L2cap packet

Comment: Emil do you please have an Idea?